# XCode: Find which event was fired without a breakpoint

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm sorry if this post is in the wrong area, please advise me on where to move it if needs be.

I've just been passed a project from a previous developer and to be honest the repository is horrendous, the previous developer used awful naming conventions, the code is completely serial, no XCAssets, XIB's or Storyboards were used and I'm finding the whole project very hard to navigate - oh and no comments! What sort of developer leaves no comments...

So far it has taken me 4 hours to fix problems that would normally take a matter of minutes due to having to scour through 200 different source files.

I was wondering if there is a way to tell the debugger to stop each time a function is called on a click events - basically on the UI there is a button which is displaying the wrong dialog, due to awful naming conventions I am finding it near impossible to locate the place in the source for me to make changes.

Any advice would be appreciated (I have told the team I am planning to rebuild the whole app, but we are due to launch next week).

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming. You are able to add a custom forwarding delegate to the AppDelegate on the Main start up that will intercept events such as the ones you described above via int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"MyListenerHere", nil);

Comment: Hey thanks, haha I've been used to working on well documented projects - my brain almost exploded when I saw this mess :P...would you care to provide an answer so I can credit your for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of programming. You are able to add a custom forwarding delegate to the AppDelegate on the Main start up that will intercept events such as the ones you described above via

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"MyListenerHere", nil)
```